# How do I restrict what topics a user can ask about when using LangChain?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain

I am currently working on a chatbot project using LangChain and OpenAI. My goal is to have the chatbot respond exclusively to questions related to marketing. However, I'm encountering an issue with controlling the user's questions using LangChain.

**What I've Tried:**

I have implemented the following steps to restrict the chatbot's responses to marketing-related questions:
i've tried to use Hugging Face Transformers library's zero-shot classification pipeline with the Facebook BART model for Natural Language Inference (MNLI).

**Question:**

Is there a specific approach or functionality within LangChain that I should be using to better control the user's questions and ensure the chatbot responds only to marketing-related queries?

Comment: What did Ai suggest you do to improve the performance?

Comment: To improve performance, I can utilize prompt engineering, but the problem is that I don't know how to do that. Someone suggested using LangChain to control user questions, but after reading the documentation, the idea of how to use it remains unclear to me.